# Kibana UI always shows status page after ElasticSearch restart

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm using Open Distro for ElasticSearch with Docker (Docker Compose) and on first boot everything works fine. However, after restarting the Docker containers Kibana always redirects me to the status page no matter what link I click in the menu. I cannot seem to find any errors in the container stderr or browser console.

Screenshot of the Kibana status page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJGUb.jpg

Comment: Can you share the status page screenshot?

Comment: @MichaelDz: Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Open Distro Security plugin: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security-kibana-plugin/issues/1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed now and you could upgrade your Docker and RPM accordingly.